# ASP.Net - App_Data & App_Code folders?

Tags: asp.net, app-code, app-data

What is the point of having `App_code` & `App_data` folders?

Why doesn't my objectDataSource detect classes unless files are in App_Code?

Please provide as much detail as you can, I'm new to ASP.Net

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These folders have special purpose. From this article - [ASP.NET Web project folder structure.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx)

App_Code

---

App_Code contains source code for shared classes and business objects (for example, ..cs, and .vb files) that you want to compile as part of your application. In a dynamically compiled Web site project, ASP.NET compiles the code in the App_Code folder on the initial request to your application. Items in this folder are then recompiled when any changes are detected.

Note : You can add any type of class file to the App_Code folder in order to create strongly typed objects that represent those classes. For example, if you put Web service files (.wsdl and .xsd files) in the App_Code folder, ASP.NET creates strongly typed proxies for those classes.

Code in the App_Code folder is referenced automatically in your application. The App_Code folder can contain sub-directories of files, which can include class files that in different programming languages.

App_Data

---

Contains application data files including .mdf database files, XML files, and other data store files. The App_Data folder is used by ASP.NET to store an application's local database, such as the database for maintaining membership and role information.

Comment: Latter link's dead.

Comment: You should not give links as the sole answer to the question.

Answer (score 26):

To sum it up :

- **IIS will NEVER serve any file** located in those folders (the same way it will not ever serve the Web.config file)
- files in the `App_Code` folder will automatically be recompiled when a change occurs in the code.

Answer (score 5):

They're mainly used with the Website template. Use the ASP.NET project template instead and avoid using these folders, especially if you are creating libraries or user controls.

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/01/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx