# Visual studio cannot detect newly created class for asp.net "website"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to modify an existing .net "website" project by adding a new class to it. I added my class inside the App_Code folder (let's call this class "ClassA"), and tried to access it from the outside in an aspx.cs file. For some reason, right after I created the class, I can create an instance of it in my aspx.cs file without any warnings from Visual Studio (e.g., ClassA a = new ClassA()). But every time I rebuild the project, I get the following Error from visual studio (The type or namespace name 'ClassA' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)). What am I missing here?

Code for Class A -> App_Code/ClassA.cs

```
public class ClassA
{
  public string test;
}
```

Code for Test.aspx.cs

```
namespace A{
  public class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ClassA a = new ClassA(); // line with error
    }
  }
}
```

If I put everything in Test.aspx.cs I get no errors:

```
namespace A{
  public class ClassA
  {
    public string test;
  }

  public class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ClassA a = new ClassA(); // no error!
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you modified the namespace of the ClassA?, as by default it append the folder name(.App+Code) in Namespace.

Comment: Is it a web *site* or a web *project*? A website is not really compiled in compile-time (no output DLL), while a web project is (a single output DLL). If it's a web project and you've got code in App_Code, it's going to result in you having the class there twice (once runtime compiled from App_Code, and once again in the compiled DLL).

Comment: Have you tried deleting your Temporary ASP.NET Files folder? I've had this happen to me a few times. A restart fixed the problem in those cases. There was an open file handle on the Temporary ASP.NET files, so the old DLL's were not being removed.

Comment: Please check this post, It will help you:

[App_Code and App_Data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480437/asp-net-app-data-app-code-folders

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default the classes inside **App_Code** folder has property "**Build Action**" set as "**Content**".

If you want to use it you need to set its "**Build Action**" property to "**Compile**".

This should work.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if this was the solution that solved the problem, but I tried a bunch of things suggested in this thread (this solution was the last thing I tried) and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: Eric@nothing else was needed. Your namespace and code was good.

Answer (score 3):

I am really sorry, for I could not totally understand the problem. 
In my opinion **you should not use namespaces when you create a class in app_code** and let it be accessible to the whole website project.
In this instance you have added a namespace, try adding:

```
using b;
```

where b is your namespace you used in your new class. This should solve your problem.

Comment: so I removed the namespace in the class definition file in App_code. I'm still getting the same error in my aspx.cs file outside of app_code (The type or namespace name 'ClassA' could not be found)

Comment: @EricChen Please update your question with the current code you're using.